# Log4Net printing "ThreadID" and "Thread Name" in the log

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, log4net

In our apps we usually name the threads that we create. For example, we would create a thread and give it a name like "WorkerThread".

Let's say this is part of my log4net config file:

```
 <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="C:\Logs\MyApp\myapp.log" />
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
      <maximumFileSize value="1000MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMin value="DEBUG" />
        <levelMax value="FATAL" />
      </filter>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c :: %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
```

This configuration will print the following in my log:

```
2017-03-07 17:00:00,003 [MessagePump Worker] DEBUG MyApp.App :: Blah Blah Blah
```

I would like it to print:

```
2017-03-07 17:00:00,003 [MessagePump Worker: 2380] DEBUG MyApp.App :: Blah Blah Blah
```

I am just trying to figure out what I need to put in my Conversion Pattern to also include the ThreadID (2380) as in my example above. I have done some google searches but I can't seem to find a way to print both the "Thread Name" and "Thread ID". Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: [Consider NLog](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Layout-RendererNets)

Comment: Maybe you could create a custom logger wrapper and add the ThreadID manually?
Take a look at this link:

https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/example-apps.html

Here it is discussed how you extend log4net with a custom EventID (used it myself before). I think you can use this method to add the ThreadID instead of the EventID.

Comment: It's as if I need a custom `ConversionPattern`

Comment: @HansPassant - would be a tough sell to management if this is the only reason to switch from log4net to nlog

Comment: Did you tried using %thread instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your application thread use:

```
ThreadContext.Properties["threadid"] = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
```

in the conversion pattern:

```
%property{threadid}
```

Answer (score 4):

It may be impossible outside of manually adding a ThreadContext.Property, like in @Wouter's answer.

See the documentation here:

[PatternLayout Class](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-2.0.8/release/sdk/index.html)

> thread | Used to output the name of the thread that generated the logging event. Uses the thread number if no name is available.

So you only get a thread id if the thread name doesn't exist. I'm frustrated with this myself, as I only want thread ids, even when a thread is named.

Comment: How do we tell log4net to not use the name but the id?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a hook

   ```
   public class Log4NetLogLevelTranslator : ILog4NetLogLevelTranslator
   {
    public Level TranslateLogLevel(LogLevel logLevel, Log4NetProviderOptions options)
    {
      //To use the real threadId
      //if (ThreadContext.Properties["threadId"] == null)
      //    ThreadContext.Properties["threadId"] = Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId;

      if (ThreadContext.Properties["threadId"] == null)
         ThreadContext.Properties["threadId"] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N").ToLower();

      return logLevel switch
      {
        LogLevel.Trace => Level.Trace,
         LogLevel.Debug => Level.Debug,
         LogLevel.Information => Level.Info,
         LogLevel.Warning => Level.Warn,
         LogLevel.Error => Level.Error,
         LogLevel.Critical => Level.Critical,
         LogLevel.None => Level.Off,
         _ => Level.Error
      };
    }
   }
   ```
2. Startup

   ```
   Logging.AddLog4Net(new Log4NetProviderOptions { Log4NetConfigFileName = path, LogLevelTranslator = new Log4NetLogLevelTranslator() });
   ```
3. Conversion pattern config
   %property{threadId}

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**